# Django db driver for AWS Neptune

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-neptune

Is there a Django driver for AWS Neptune. As I would be using Neptune Graph DB with Django and was wondering would there be a driver available for it.

Comment: When you say driver, what specifically are you referring to? Are you talking about an sdk for the management apis, or sdk to talk to the gremlin endpoint, or perhaps an sdk to talk to the sparql endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a neptune - django library. There is a gremlin-python library that can be used to connect to and query Neptune. Amazon provides an example of its usage here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-python.html